# vb - I am trying to print other form but this happens:

Tags: vb.net

(this is my first post so correct me if I'm doing something wrong.)

Here is a bit of my code:

```
imp.id.Text = globalvars.mdataset.Tables("table1").Rows(0).Item("id")
    imp.date.Text = globalvars.mdataset.Tables("table1").Rows(0).Item("date")
    imp.hour.Text = globalvars.mdataset.Tables("table1").Rows(0).Item("hour").ToString
    imp.PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(10, 10, 10, 10)
    imp.Show()
    imp.Focus()
    imp.PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    imp.PrintForm1.Print()
```

and what happens is that when it gives me the preview the page is empty... but the weird thing is that when i place a msgbox just before the printing action, the preview goes right and shows me what i want to print.... 
any tips?

EDIT: **imp** is the form where the printform is

Comment: sorry .. but what var is **imp** ?

Comment: imp is the form where the printform is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this ..

```
....
Application.DoEvents
imp.PrintForm1.Print()
```